# ReactNative Expo Redux ReferenceError: Can't find variable: document

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, referenceerror

expo: <s>3.27.4</s> => 4.1.3

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: <s>0.62.2</s> => 0.63.4

@reduxjs/toolkit: 1.5.0

react-redux: 7.2.2

redux: 4.0.5

I'm new to react-native and am trying to implement Redux into my Expo app.
This code builds multiple times (I assume this is because of the expo registerRootComponent(App)) and then once it runs I get a:

**"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: document"**

My index.js where the error occurs currently looks like this:

```
    import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

    import App from './App'
    import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
    import store from './app/store'
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux'


    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    )

    registerRootComponent(App);
```

I've also tried putting into it's own function in, because I've had a similar error where this helped.

```
function App () {
    return (
        ReactDOM.render(
          <Provider store={store}>
              <MainFunc />
          </Provider>,
          document.getElementById('root')
        )
    )
}
```

But once again it cannot find document. Please, help me find document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Not a perfect solution.

I wasn't able to make the ReactDOM.render part work, but using hooks seems to do the job of re-rendering my components fine.

#### Step 1

Remove the RectDOM.render from index.js and replace with standard expo:

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App from './App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

#### Step 2

Surround you App() content with Provider (don't forget to import Provider and store):

```
import store from './app/store';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

function App () {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Components/>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

#### Step 3

In the component you want to reload when a change occurs in redux memory create an instance of your object:

```
  const currentTicket = useSelector((state) =>
    state.tickets.find((ticket) => ticket.id == global.currentTicketID)
  );
```

*Note: My redux store is an array of ticket objects so I must find the ticket  I want to work with using the array find function*

And then create a hook that takes in a value of your instance:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //code you want to run on change of the instance value
  }, [currentTicket.num]);
```

**Note: this only works if you have functional components** (not classes)